# Do i need to create a banner ad for each page?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

I am creating an app for Android. It has almost 13 pages(layouts). Should i create a new banner ad for each page in Admob? or just one is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose: it depends on what you mean for "enough":

if you create a banner for each layout you'll have more requests, more fills, but for lower time;

if you create just one banner, you'll have less requests, but the ad will be seen for longer time.

It depends on you, there aren't restrictions in AdMob.

Comment: I think the way with a banner for each layout, but for sure 13 are a lot... maybe a banner for 3 or 4 layouts, for a total of about 4 banners.

Comment: Or if you have a more visited layout, use a banner just for that, then if maybe two layouts are seen for a few time, use the same banner for both

Comment: but which approach will give you more revenue? 
One banner with longer time or multiple banners for shorter times?